# Define a constant variable in codeigniter in hooks

Tags: codeigniter, hook, constants

I have a hook which basically throws a user to login page if session empty.

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    'class' => 'Status',
    'function' => 'logInCheck',
    'filename' => 'hooks.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params' => array()
);
```

Now in the hook function of `logInCheck` I want to define some constant variables. When I googled I found that constants can only be defined in constants.php or config.php. Now my query is to define it in a hook file.

When I tried this `define('HEADERFILE', 'deafult_header');`

I am getting this error

> Message: Use of undefined constant HEADERFILE - assumed 'HEADERFILE'

So how can I define a constant inside a hook file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Google is right. Right way to define constants is to define seperate file constants.php and place it in /application/config, then to load this file in your controller the following way

$this->config->load('constants.php');

Soo... why this solution doesn't suit you? What is the problem?

Comment: As I said I am setting the constant on session check in a hook file, so I cant use it in a config file